# Examples of algorithms that have runtime O(N + M) resp O(NM)

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, asymptotics

I'm looking for examples of loops that have running time $O(nm)$, $O(n+m)$ and $O(n\log m)$ to help me understand these concepts.  Could anybody give some examples and explain why they have the given running time?

Comment: Questions that contain a full answer don't work too well, here (and, actually, the answers weren't quite right). I edited the question to take the answers out, and posted an answer containing corrected versions of them. QuiteNothing, I hope I captured the original intent of your question: if not, please edit so I'm not putting words into your mouth!

Comment: I'm afraid there is not much conceptual understanding to be gained from this.

Comment: QuiteNothing, what research and study have you done on your own?  We expect you to make a serious effort on your own, and when a topic is covered well by existing textbooks, there's not a lot of value to going over it again on this site.

Comment: This answer similes with my question!! Just wanted to check if my understanding is correct. Thanks guys

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following fragment sets `t` to a value that is $O(nm)$ (actually, it's equal to $mn$). the outer loop executes $n$ times and, each of those times, the inner loop executes $m$ times.

```
t = 0;
for i=1 to n do
    for j=1 to m do
        t = t+1;
```

The following fragment runs the first loop $n$ times and then runs the second loop $m$ more times, for a total of $n+m$ (which is a trivial example of $O(n+m)$).

```
t = 0;
for i = 1 to n do
    t = t+1;
for i = 1 to m do
    t = t+1;
```

Finally, this fragment runs the outer loop $n$ times.  Each time, `p` is set to $m$ and then halved until it reaches 1. This answers the question "How many times do I have to multiply 1 by 2 to get something bigger than $m$, which is $\log_2 m$. So the value of $t$ is $O(n\log m)$.  (We don't need to worry about the base of the logarithm, since $\log_a m = k\log_b m$ for some constant $k$, which all gets lost in the $O(-)$.)

```
t = 0;
for i = 1 to n do
    p = m;
    while (p > 1) do
        p = p/2;
        t = t+1;
```

---

The code fragments here are similar to the ones that appeared in the original version of the question. I removed them from the question, since questions that contain answers aren't well-suited to this site.